# What is the meaning of this datasheet diameter notation?

Tags: pcb, datasheet, encoder, drill

I am reading this datasheet and I want to drill the correct size hole into the board and I am confused what 5-ø1.2 means.

[image: This diameter notation]

I can't understand what the 5 and - sign mean? Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It means that there are 5 (quantity) of these holes, each has a diameter of 1.2 mm (+0.1 mm / -0 mm).

Answer (score 28):

[image]

There are 5 holes (marked in blue) that need to be drilled 1.2 mm diameter.

It doesn't mean 5 minus 1.2 OR 5 minus \$\phi\$

Answer (score 14):

It means there are five of that hole somewhere on the diagram. Each one is nominally 1.2mm in diameter and can be up to 0.1mm larger than nominal or 0mm smaller than nominal.